# how to get query selector data attribute in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, custom-data-attribute

I have a custom JS function that creates/inject a custom link into all elements in the page when it loads.

Before manipulation:

```
<div class="myimagediv">
       <img class="img-tag" src="#" data-src="alternative content I need" alt="">
    </div>
```

and now this custom function manipulates the element:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.myimagediv'), function(elem) {
            old_html = elem.innerHTML;

            new_html = '<a class="customlink" href="' + elem.querySelector('img').src + '">' + old_html + '</a>';
            elem.innerHTML = new_html;
        });
```

The newly manipulate element:

```
<div class="myimagediv">
      <a class="customlink" href="this should be the content of my data-src" title="">
          <img class="img-tag" src="#" data-src="alternative content I need" alt="">
      </a>    
    </div>
```

How can I get the data-src attribute from the IMG tag and inject it into my newly created custom link function?

I should use a var? and then call it, but I cannot grasp how to read the data-src and re-use it.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `var dataSrc = elem.querySelector('img').getAttribute('data-src');`

Comment: Try elem.querySelector('img').dataset.src

Comment: @Jared Smith please submit it as answer as that is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks! :-)

Comment: @user2513846 done.

Comment: @user2513846 - Take a look for my example - especially how to read multi word data attributes like data-something-else.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just use the `getAttribute` method of the image element:

```
var dataSrc = elem.querySelector('img').getAttribute('data-src');
```

Answer (score 5):

Example - how to read data-* attrs in vanilla JS:

```js
var elm = document.querySelector('any-tag')
var first = elm.dataset.whatever
var second = elm.dataset.somethingElse // camel case for multi-word

console.log(first, second)
```

```html
<any-tag data-whatever="value1" data-something-else="value2" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to get it like any other attribute

```
<div id="test" data-myattr="toto">

</div>

alert(document.getElementById("test").getAttribute("data-myattr"));
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/L4ncvL6v/)

*EDIT FROM **@waldemarice**:*

**HtmlElement** contains the **dataset** property to get attribut prefixed by data-

```
    <div id="test" data-myattr="toto">

    </div>

  alert(document.getElementById("test").dataset.myattr);
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/L4ncvL6v/2/)

Comment: For data atrributes there is dataset. No need read it as any other attrs.

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelectorAll()` example:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.className').forEach(elem => console.log(elem.getAttribute('interesting-attribute')));
```